# Angular-Carousel Module fails to load

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-carousel

I´m trying to implement the image gallery "angular-carousel" on my site. But Angular throws an error, when loading carousel:

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.14/$injector/modulerr?p0=myApp&p1=Error%3A%…gleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.3.14%2Fangular.min.js%3A17%3A381)

I'm running on Node and Express and I used a CDN Source for angular-carousel:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-carousel/0.3.12/angular-carousel.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-carousel/0.3.12/angular-carousel.js"></script>
```

This is where I´d like to place the carousel:

```
<ul rn-carousel class="image">
    <li ng-repeat="x in img">
        <img ng-src="/uploads/{{project._id}}/{{x}}"/>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And here´s my Controller part:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'angular-carousel']);
    app.controller('ProjectController',  function($scope,$http){
        var url = window.location.pathname;
        var id = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
        $http.get('/projects_view/'+id).success(function(data){ 
            $scope.project = data;
        });
        $http.get('/getpics/'+id).success(function (files){
            $scope.img = files;             
        });         
    });
```

Without carousel image loading works perfectly.
Hoping for help :)

Comment: I think you are missing `angular-touch.js` reference

Comment: Yes this solved the error! But still no gallery there!? Have I implemented it wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed to `angular-touch.js` because while creating `angular-carousel` module it needs `ng-touch` dependency, That's why while creating a `angular-carousel` module it search for `ngTouch` module. And which is not available there, So angular throws an `$injector/modulerr` error.

**Code**

```
angular.module('angular-carousel', [
    'ngTouch',
    'angular-carousel.shifty'
]);
```

Above code [**link here**](https://github.com/revolunet/angular-carousel/blob/master/dist/angular-carousel.js#L16-L19) in `angular-carousel.js` API.

Comment: Thank you for solving the error! Any idea why i still can`t see the carousel? No error throwing anymore, but no images.

Comment: @Wandkleister does `files` contains an array of files collection?

Comment: It is an array of filenames, which i use in ng-repeat.

Comment: It worked to list all the images in one folder. But carousel needs an array of files not paths, am I right? Do you have an idea for a workaround?

Comment: @Wandkleister you are correct, you need to have return all of `fileName` that would apply on each element by looping on it like `$scope.img = ["a.jpg", "b.jpg"];`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85507/discussion-between-wandkleister-and-pankaj-parkar).